# Help "Install" Module for Python using WGET

Tags: python

I am trying to setup this python library and am having a very hard time.  I suspect it is because I am a hobby programmer, but I have successfully installed programs in the past using the command line.  I am using Windows and Python 2.6.

The help that is shown below is taken from the website.

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/y/yql/yql-0.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf yql-0.2.tar.gz
cd yql-0.2
python setup.py install
```

In doing a number of Google searches, it seems that this is for Unix/Mac commands.  My previous process has not worked, so I am looking for all of the help I can get.

Many thanks in advance!

- Brock

Here is the error:

```
>>> import yql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\yql-0.6-py2.5.egg\yql\__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    class Public(object):
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\yql-0.6-py2.5.egg\yql\__init__.py", line 229, in Public
    @scheme.setter
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'setter'
```

Comment: your error shows "c:\python25" not python2.6 Run setup.py using python2.6

Comment: sorry. I have two separate machines, one with 2.5, the other 2.6, but I can't get it running on either machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are definately Unix/Linux commands to install python module. The installation in windows is pretty much similar. Follow the instructions given below

1. Download the library from the website.
2. Extract it using Winzip or WinRAR.
3. It will create a directory with name like foo-0.2. The directory should contain a script named setup.py
4. Now open the command prompt and cd to that directory
5. At command prompt type following
   python setup.py install

Also check the following link for more detailed instructions

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/install/index.html

Comment: Good instructions. I don't think winzip can open a .tar.gz archive though. Use 7zip for a free software archiver that can extract files from tar.gz archives (http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I did this exactly.  I dont believe I received any errors when I ran this process.  I modified the question above so you can see the error I am getting when I simply try to import yql.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are all the dependant modules already installed? Check https://launchpad.net/python-yql, it lists all the module on which yql is dependent upon. Install any missing ones and then try again

Comment: I didn't think of that, but it solved it for one machine anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What's the error message? Also what OS are you using? The install instructions seem fine.

In Debian & in most Unix Systems you could also these -

1. `sudo pip install <module_name>` to install any module.
2. or `sudo easy_install <module_name>`
3. or `sudo apt-get install <module_name>`
4. or you could do what you mentioned in the question. Should work fine.

Maybe you don't have **root access**. Package installation needs that. Post more info for more constructive comments. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you install setuptools first (see [setuptools on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)) and add C:\Python26\Scripts to your PATH variable you can run the following:

```
easy_install yql-0.2.tar.gz
```

after wgetting the archive.

Or even easier, without wgetting the archive, simply run:

```
easy_install yql
```

And it'll download and install the latest version of yql with all the dependencies.

Comment: Also, if you're running Vista or Win7 make sure you open the command prompt as Administrator.

Comment: I ran this on my machine at work (XP), and the easy_install appeared to work.  When I ran the import yql, I got a error message on something httplib2 (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer for installing wget is to download [wget for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget).

Download the tar file and unpack the file

Then cd to the folder and run in terminal

```
python setup.py install
```

This is to install **wget** into Python

Comment: This question isn't about installing wget or a Python module for wget; it's about installing the yql Python module.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

import tensorflow
word2vec_path = 'YOUR LINK HERE'
word2vec = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_path, binary=True)